# How to reference the $scope in which a directive is applied?

Tags: angularjs, fine-uploader

I have a custom directive that uploads a file to amazon and contains a `callback(onComplete)`.
When the callback is complete, I would like to attach a value to the `$scope` of the controller in which the directive is created. In this case, the scope of `Invite`.

Both `Invite` and `fineUploader` extend the same angular module.

**HTML(simplified):**

```
<div ng-controller="Invite" class="apply">
    <div fine-uploader ng-switch-when="file"  upload-extensions="jpg,jpeg,png,gif"></div>
</div>
```

**Directive:**

```
directive('fineUploader', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function($scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            $scope.uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
                debug: true,
                element: element[0],
                request: {
                    endpoint: 'ballentines-bar-project.s3.amazonaws.com',
                    accessKey: 'AKIAIPT6J4T6XZXV3VWA'
                },callbacks: {
                    onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                        if (responseJSON.success === true) {
                            console.log(this.getKey(id));
                            console.log($scope);
                            $scope.test = this.getKey(id);
                        }
                    }
                },
                signature: {
                    endpoint: '/s3/'
                },
                iframeSupport: {
                    localBlankPagePath: '/success.html'
                },
                retry: {
                    enableAuto: true // defaults to false
                },
                deleteFile: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                text: {
                    uploadButton: '<p>Upload File</p>'
                },
                template:
                    '<div class="qq-uploader">' +
                        '<div class="qq-upload-button btn btn-info">{uploadButtonText}</div>' +
                        '<ul class="qq-upload-list" ><h2>Your files</h2></ul>' +
                    '</div>',
            });
        }
    };
}).
```

**Controller**

```
controller('Invite', function(
    $scope,
    $localStorage,
    $http
){
    $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
        "formkey": "1MRSAWTRl5-PnVEoy3tD63BL3q_v2mnAhtqa9bdZk-zg",
        "draftResponse": "[]",
        "pageHistory": "0",
    });
    $scope.liking = liking;
    $scope.post = function(){
        $http.post('/signup.php', $scope.$storage).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                console.log(data);
        });
    };
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
        function(href, widget) {
            liking = true;
        }
    );
})
```

Comment: Why do you use isolate scope aka `scope: {}`. The directive in this case uses private scope. Try to remove it

Comment: Good point(updated) though this doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: can you post relevant part of your controller?

Answer (score 2):

I would try at least two options:

**[1]**

change  `scope: {},` in directive to:

```
   `scope: { test: '@'},`
```

This makes the `test` method visible in the private scope.

**[2]**

The second option try removing the isolate scope a.e: `scope: {},`

Comment: For option 2, then what? I tried console.log($scope); it still seems to be the wrong scope.

Comment: do you get with debugger to `$scope.test = this.getKey(id);` row?

Comment: yes, though, I would like it to be in the parents parents parents scope :)

Answer (score 2):

You either need to pass the items from the parent scope to the directive (through isolated scope).  Or, do as @MaximShoustin says and remove the isolated scope from your directive.

**So, option 1:**

```
scope: { directiveProperty: '=nameOfAttributeThatContainsParentProperty' },
```

**Or, option 2:**

Remove the isolated scope declaration `scope: {},` from the directive.  This will allow the directive to extend the scope of it's containing scope.

Comment: For option 2, then what? I tried                            console.log($scope); it still seems to be the wrong scope.

Comment: The scope I want to reference contains a key called $localStorage(in the Angular debugger I can determine it's the parents parents parents scope.)